# Create tar archive without folders where only the name of the folder is known (recurring)

Tags: unix, tar, synology

I have a synology DS213j. I have installed PhotoStation on it and it created some @eaDir folders in all my folders in order to create some thumbnails pictures.
I have for example this:

```
/photo
/photo/2012
/photo/@eaDir
/photo/2012/Album1
/photo/2012/Album2
/photo/2012/@eaDir
/photo/2012/Album1/SubAlbum1
/photo/2012/Album1/SubAlbum2
/photo/2012/Album1/@eaDir
```

I would like to tar my folder 2012 in order to send that to Amazon Glacier for backup. I don't want to use .zip because I may have some files of more than 4Gb which is too much for zip.

I have done this:

```
tar -cvzf 2012.tar.gz 2012/
```

It worked but included all the folders named @eaDir.

My questions is. I would like to exclude all the @eaDir folders from my tar file.

I have tried to use the --exclude function but it seems it's not valid on the Synology. Maybe I need to install another package to have another tar function to be able to use that. Maybe I can use regex function in order to achieve what I want.

Can someone help me with that? (with --exclude or regex or anything else)

Comment: It seems I can use the -X option of the tar which seems to be the same as the --exclude.

Comment: I tried this tar -cvz -X @eaDir -f 2012.tar.gz  2012 but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

i did not find it easy to exclude the specified file ..... tried find with prune , X option    --exclude=PATTERN option and   --exclude-tag-under=FILE   options of tar but the empty directory or the contents of @eaDir get packed in the end result....Also tried a small script to supply names to add in zip in a while loop , that brought me to a small question ....

in your question you said : " it created some @eaDir folders in all my folders in order to create some thumbnails pictures"  .... is that directory @eaDir or its content important to you ?

it would be a lot simpler if you did just remove them with :

```
find ./photo -iname "@eaDir" -ok rm -rf {} \;
```

and then use tar on that ....

```
 tar -cvf photo.tar ./photo
```

Comment: Hi! Actually these folders were created automatically by PhotoStation (a synology app that creates for viewing pictures). I want to keep these folders on my Synology, however I don't want to back them up.

Comment: if you delete them , wont they be created by the system if you access/view the photo's again ?

Comment: Hmmm that's a possibility, but I would like to avoid this. Can't we do it with tar (that would the best option for me). Regenerating the thumbnails can take days...